# using MemoryStreams as content sources when attaching files to email, C#

Tags: c#, email, memorystream, attachment

So, I've been having a bit of trouble trying to attach files using a MemoryStream as a content source.

Right now, I'm fetching images from a remote web server and trying to package them into an email that functions as a daily report.

I've gotten the fetching, parsing, and image extraction all down, and I've tested that it works. The problem I'm facing is that when I create an Attachment object using a MemoryStream as the content source/content stream, the email contains a blank file/image.  However, when I specify an actual file that resides on the hard drive, it attaches to the message with no problem and the message received is perfect.

Obviously, I would rather not have to cache any of the images locally before I attach the files and send them since this will create unnecessary overhead with the caching and then purging them. But, if need be, I can make this my last resort.

My question is if there is some known issue with using a MemoryStream as the contentStream when creating an Attachment object, or if there is something I'm forgetting.

Thanks!

Comment: Post the relevant portion of code that isn't working and add what are you using to create the email. Outlook? EWS? some other library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm trying my psychic debugging powers: you've loaded your MemoryStream with data and forgotten to reset position to zero before reading out of it. If so,

```
myMemoryStream.Position = 0
```

in a tactical position might help.

Comment: +1. I'd recommend instead setting Position=0 to create cloned r/o memory stream over the same byte array as original MemoryStream.

Comment: man, your powers are amazing! this is exactly what the problem was. but man oh man, do I feel stupid now.